# Getting wrong output from reading lines in a file in c program

Tags: c, arrays

I need to get this output:

```
P1  0   3
P2  1   6
P3  4   4
P4  6   2
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

I am new to C programming. So, I don't know why I am getting wrong output. This is what I did. I am supposed to store each column in different variable. Because After storing them in different variable I need to do maths calculation for them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fptr != NULL) {
        size_t i;
        int SIZE = 1000;
        int*x[500]; 
        int*y[500]; 
        int*z[500]; 
        int ch=0;
        int l;
        int n=0;
        char line[100];

        while ((ch=fgetc (fptr))!= EOF) {
            if (ch=='\n')
            n++;
        }

        printf("Number of lines = %d\n", n);

        for (l=0; l<n;++l) {
            while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fptr)) { 
                printf("%s",line);
                sscanf(line,"%d %d %d",&x[l],&y[l],&z[l]);
            } 
        }

        for (i=0; i<l;++i) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n",x[i],y[i],z[i]);
        }

        fclose(fptr);
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: You should `rewind()` the `fptr` after counting lines, as it has gone up to the end of file.

Comment: The lines beginning with `P` are the needed output? What is the input? Where do the `P` come from?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least 2 issues.

1. The `fptr` has gone to the end of file while counting number of lines. So `rewind()` the `fptr` after counting lines, as it has gone up to the end of file. So add `rewind(fptr)` after first while loop.
2. You do not need `x, y, z` as array of pointers, rather just an array. So change them to

   ```
   int x[500]; 
   int y[500]; 
   int z[500];
   ```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Now my output is like this.                                        0 0 975162241
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
I wondering whether am I using the sizeof function incorrectly.

Comment: @BryanSim, `'P1'` cannot be read as integer using `'%d'`, hence probably you are getting the incorrect output. Try using `'%s'` instead and then you need to change `x` to store strings.

Comment: hey i did some changes, now I read them as %s and column 1 and column 2 as %i

Comment: i think i am not able to store them properly because of my sizeof function?? Because I need to store them in array

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets sort this out with comments first:

```
#include<stdio.h>
// i dont think the following includes are nessesary for the given code
//#include<stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
//#include <stdint.h>
//#include <stdbool.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fptr;
    // i wonder a little about what youre opening here with argv[1]
    // since arrays start counting at 0
    // for testing and more understandability maybe just put the file
    // where your code is and deliver its filename as a string?
    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fptr != NULL) {
        // whats that? you use it as a counting variable, make it int
        // not size_t
        size_t i;
        // its not good practive to have a variable in capitals
        // if you wanna make it a constant, you should define it
        // at the beginning of the code, right after your includes
        int SIZE = 1000;
        // dont use pointers (these -> "*") here! Maybe you mix up
        // dynamic array declaration (which requires using malloc() and
        // no brackets like "int * dynArray;") with static arrays
        // correct usage would be: int x[500]; thats it
        int*x[500]; 
        int*y[500]; 
        int*z[500]; 
        int ch=0;
        // just a hint for more readability: use "j" instead of "l" but
        // thats really up to you :D
        int l;
        int n=0;
        char line[100];

        // here you loop through your file char by char and just count
        // the lines. Why dont pick the chars on the fly and actually
        // write something into your defined arrays x, y, z ?
        // some additional conditions (if) may do the trick
        while ((ch=fgetc (fptr))!= EOF) {
            if (ch=='\n')
            n++;
        }

        printf("Number of lines = %d\n", n);

        // sizeof is a function, so youre missing the parentheses
        // and above that, you already know the size of your line array
        // because its statically defined to hold 100 * sizeof(char)
        // my suggestion: trash this entire loop and rethink the previous
        for (l=0; l<n;++l) {
            while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fptr)) { 
                printf("%s",line);
                sscanf(line,"%d %d %d",&x[l],&y[l],&z[l]);
            } 
        }

        // cool loop. but there was no input to x, y, z except the first
        // element of your line array, which seems to hold just a 0
        // so everythings correct here, the mistake occured before
        for (i=0; i<l;++i) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n",x[i],y[i],z[i]);
        }

        //nice, thats important :)
        fclose(fptr);
        return 0 ;
    }
```

i hope it helps you sort out things and may guide to a clearer question which maybe answeres itself? :D